# Why, for any $x\in S^{n-1}$, does there exists a matrix in $SO(n)$ which takes $e_1$ to $x$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Why is it true that for any $x \in S^{n-1}$ (the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$) there exists a matrix $U \in SO(n)$ such that $Ue_1=x$? Here $e_1$ denotes the first element from standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

If one replaces the first element of the standard basis by $x$ and forms a new orthonormal basis by Gram-Schmidt process then the change of basis matrix, say $U$, is orthogonal and takes $e_1$ to $x$. But how can I ensure that this $U$ is going to have determinant $+1$? Thanks.

Comment: Presumably $n \ge 2$: it's not true for $n=1$.

Answer (score 3):

Case 1: the linear span $V$ of $x$ and $e_1$ is two-dimensional.  Find a rotation of $V$ that takes $e_1$ to $x$, and map $V^\perp$ to itself by the identity.

Case 2: the linear span is one-dimensional.  Take a suitable rotation in the span of $e_1$ and $e_2$...